# WooCommerce custom related products on shop/catalog page with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a WooCommerce shop and want to be able to display custom related products, for each product, on the shop/catalog page.

**My setup**

Using Advanced Custom Fields Pro

I have created a field group with a RELATION field called: product_relations

For each product I have selected several 'custom related products' via the product_relations field option on the product page in the backend.

I then created a shortcode to be visible on the shop/catalog page.

I do see output only not the output I would like.

**The current output**

I only see the relations of the LATEST PRODUCT >> See screenshot

[image: Current output]

Here's my code I have so far:

```
function yl_product_relations_shortcode() {
    global $product;

    $product_relations = get_field('product_relations');

    if ($product_relations) {

        $output .= '<ul class="uk-thumbnav uk-margin-bottom">';

        foreach ($product_relations as $product_relation) {
            $title  = get_the_title($product_relation);
            $image  = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product_relation);
            $url    = get_the_permalink($product_relation);

            $output .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '" uk-tooltip="' . $title . '"><img src="' . $image . '" class="uk-border-rounded" width="40"></a></li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';

    }

    return $output;

}

add_shortcode('yl_product_relations','yl_product_relations_shortcode');
```

**Nobody?**
I use the WordPress Cusomizer and I'm using a shortcode to collect te data.

`[yl_product_relations]`

When I try to add the product_id like this

```
$id = $product->get_id();
$product_relations = get_field('product_relations', $id);
```

I get an error. Probably because I'm using the customizer and therefor not really coding within the product loop itself..?

Comment: Are you using this shortcode _once_ on the page (and expect it to display data related to multiple products), or are you using it somewhere within the product loop, trying to get related products for each one individually?

Comment: I'm using the Wordpress customizer to display the products (via dynamic content). So it looks like I'm working in the product loop but probably it just looks like it....? I display the product this way because I'm done with editing all the WoooCommerce template files.... Any idea how to get the product id in this case?

Comment: But does that shortcode execute once per page, or once per product? If it is the former - and you want to show related products for _all_ the products on the current page, in one go - then you can't work with just _one_ product ID in your shortcode callback function to begin with; you'd need the ID of _all_ products on the current page, and then fetch the ACF field content for each of them in a loop.